# Cookie not recognised on subdomain

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I have a domain and a subdomain which I need both to recognise a cookie set by the main domain. On www.mydomain.com I set the cookie with Javascript like so:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);
var c = "all; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + "; path=/;domain=mydomain.com";
document.cookie = "cookies=" + c;
```

In the PHP I use a simple `if (isset($_COOKIE['cookies'])) ...` This works on www.mydomain.com but it doesn't work on sub.mydomain.com.

Any suggestions? Do I have to call the cookie within PHP differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 30);
var c = "all; expires=" + d.toUTCString() + "; path=/;domain=.mydomain.com";
document.cookie = "cookies=" + c;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `domain=mydomain.com` to `domain=.mydomain.com` (notice the preceding dot). Then the cookie will apply to all subdomains.